# Apache Spark / GraphX Restrict Map-Phase

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to build sth. like the Pregel implementation of GraphX, but I don't want to use the `mapReduceTriplets`-Function. Instead I try to use the `graph.vertices.flatMap` because I don't need triplets and vertices are sufficient.

My code skeleton looks (more or less) like

```scala
while(){
    // Create messages for other nodes and run program logic, 
    // should only run on nodes that have received a message on round before
    messages = graph.vertices.flatMap()

    // Join back nodes into graph
    newVerts= graph.innerJoin(messages)
    g : Graph = graph.outerJoinVertices(newVerts)
}
```

My problem is that in iteration `i` I want to do the flatMap operation only on that nodes that received a message on round `i-1`. With mapReduceTriplets this is done by using the activeSet that only this nodes are active, but I can't find such a operation for a VertexRDD where only the nodes are used.

Has someone an idea how to solve this problem efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, that in my case I could use the vertices of the graph of the last round and then do my calculations and join back the new values.